# How to detect if uploaded image has border upon form submission

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, image-processing

I have a user registration form (php) with image upload capability and I would like to know if it's possible to detect if the user-uploaded image has a border. If it has, I would like the form to deny the submission.

PHP, JQuery or Javascript may do. Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you possibly tried researching yet?

Comment: Check first pixel border for same color (or similar color). Use GD2 in PHP.

Comment: What if the picture has a seamless blue sky?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a PHP-GD script to check if the given image contains border. You can implement following steps to check for one-pixel border with same color:

1. Get height (h) and width (w) of the image
2. First scan horizontally, loop through (0,0) to (w,0) check if all pixels have same color
3. Then scan vertically, loop through (0,0) to (0,h) check if all pixels have same color

If pixels have same color, we can assume the picture has border. If we find complete one-pixel border using above steps, we can run it again on inner pixels to be sure.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686990/algorithm-to-find-border-color-of-an-image-in-php).